# What's Go cmd option 'gcflags' all possible values

Tags: go, compiler-optimization

I'm learning about Go memory optimization through inlining. The following code is my test code.

I use `go build -gcflags=-m=2 main.go` to get all the results. I follow [Dave Cheney's post](https://dave.cheney.net/2020/05/02/mid-stack-inlining-in-go) to do this.

My question is: What're the values of 'gcflags'? Where is the documentation, I couldn't find the doc by Google?

```
func fn1() int {
    s := 1+2
    return s
}

func fn2() string {
    a := "h"
    a += "e"
    a += "l"
    a += "l"
    a += "o"
    b := " "
    c := "w"
    c += "o"
    c += "r"
    c += "l"
    c += "d"
    d := "d"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    d += "e"
    s := a + b + c
    return s
}

func fn3() {
    p := fn1()

    s := fn2()

    println("p = " + string(p))
    println("s = " + s)
}
```

output:

```
go build -gcflags='-m=2' main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:3:6: can inline fn1 as: func() int { s := 1 + 2; return s }
./main.go:16:6: cannot inline fn2: function too complex: cost 81 exceeds budget 80
./main.go:47:6: cannot inline fn3: function too complex: cost 85 exceeds budget 80
```

**I also tried `-gcflags=-m=3, -gcflags=-m=4, -gcflags=-m=5`, the results is like below, very hard to understand. Maybe somebody can help me point out a direction.**

```
go build -gcflags=-m=3 main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:3:6: can inline fn1 as: func() int { s := 1 + 2; return s }
./main.go:8:6: cannot inline fn2: recursive
./main.go:16:6: can inline fn3 as: func() { p := fn1(); p = fn2(p); println("p = " + string(p)) }
./main.go:17:10: inlining call to fn1 func() int { s := 1 + 2; return s }
./main.go:17:10: Before inlining:
.   CALLFUNC l(17) tc(1) int
.   .   NAME-inlining.fn1 l(3) x(0) class(PFUNC) tc(1) used FUNC-@0
substituting name
.   NAME-inlining.s g(2) l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int  ->
.   NAME-inlining.s l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int
substituting name
.   NAME-inlining.s g(2) l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int  ->
.   NAME-inlining.s l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int
substituting name
.   NAME-inlining.s g(2) l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int  ->
.   NAME-inlining.s l(4) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) used int
./main.go:17:10: After inlining
.   INLCALL-init
.   .   DCL l(17)
.   .   .   NAME-inlining.~r0 l(3) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) assigned used int

.   .   AS l(17) tc(1)
.   .   .   NAME-inlining.~r0 l(3) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) assigned used int

.   .   INLMARK l(+17) x(0)
.   INLCALL l(17) tc(1) int
.   INLCALL-rlist
.   .   NAME-inlining.~r0 l(3) x(0) class(PAUTO) tc(1) assigned used int
..... // too much
```

Comment: Question like yours are much better asked on [the  mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts). There are several reasons: 1) The question is open-ended and cannot be answered with a single definitive answer; 2) AFAIK no of the Go core team watches the `[go]` tag on SO, but quite many of them are active on the mailing list.

Comment: @kostix what you say may be true, but Go core team may also help by writing some decent concise documentation that's easy to find.   [Lumping every `go` subcommand together](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go) under one page is just way too verbose, almost a form of obfuscation.

Comment: @EdRandall, I sympathize your stance on this topic, but writing such comments under a random post on SO is not going to help. If you really want something in this area to be changed, please feel free to post to the mailing list I've referred to in my first comment to the thread, or file an issue in the project's tracker. I mean, no one of those actually in position to discuss these matters won't read your comment, so it's basically venting,

Answer (score 31):

`-gcflags` flag accepts list of flags, that should be passed to `go tool compile` when it's invoked. So you can see all possible options in [its documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/) or running command:

```
go tool compile -help
```

Comment: It's not really very obvious that `go tool compile` would be the answer when the command used is `go build`.   But buried in `go help build` states (separately, near the end): 
_The -asmflags, -gccgoflags, -gcflags, and -ldflags flags accept a space-separated list of arguments to pass to an underlying tool during the build._
So devs need to know all about each individual tool that's being wrapped.

Answer (score 4):

*updated*:
cd to a folder where you have your ".go" files (project using modules)

and run:

```
go build -gcflags -help
```

***example:***

```
$ go version
go version go1.20.2

$ ls -la
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 199 Mar 20 09:04 hello.go
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 198 Mar 20 09:04 hello_test.go

$ go build -gcflags -help
# gitlab.bla.com/bla_go/modules/hello
usage: compile [options] file.go...
  -%    debug non-static initializers
  -+    compiling runtime
  -B    disable bounds checking
  -C    disable printing of columns in error messages
  -D path
        set relative path for local imports
  -E    debug symbol export
  -I directory
        add directory to import search path
  -K    debug missing line numbers
  -L    also show actual source file names in error messages for positions affected by //line directives
  -N    disable optimizations
  -S    print assembly listing
  -V    print version and exit
  -W    debug parse tree after type checking
  -asan
        build code compatible with C/C++ address sanitizer
  -asmhdr file
        write assembly header to file
  -bench file
        append benchmark times to file
  -blockprofile file
        write block profile to file
  -buildid id
        record id as the build id in the export metadata
  -c int
        concurrency during compilation (1 means no concurrency) (default 12)
  -clobberdead
        clobber dead stack slots (for debugging)
  -clobberdeadreg
        clobber dead registers (for debugging)
  -complete
        compiling complete package (no C or assembly)
  -coveragecfg file
        read coverage configuration from file
  -cpuprofile file
        write cpu profile to file
  -d value
        enable debugging settings; try -d help
  -dwarf
        generate DWARF symbols (default true)
  -dwarfbasentries
        use base address selection entries in DWARF (default true)
  -dwarflocationlists
        add location lists to DWARF in optimized mode (default true)
  -dynlink
        support references to Go symbols defined in other shared libraries
  -e    no limit on number of errors reported
  -embedcfg file
        read go:embed configuration from file
  -gendwarfinl int
        generate DWARF inline info records (default 2)
  -goversion string
        required version of the runtime
  -h    halt on error
  -importcfg file
        read import configuration from file
  -installsuffix suffix
        set pkg directory suffix
  -j    debug runtime-initialized variables
  -json string
        version,file for JSON compiler/optimizer detail output
  -l    disable inlining
  -lang string
        Go language version source code expects
  -linkobj file
        write linker-specific object to file
  -linkshared
        generate code that will be linked against Go shared libraries
  -live
        debug liveness analysis
  -m    print optimization decisions
  -memprofile file
        write memory profile to file
  -memprofilerate rate
        set runtime.MemProfileRate to rate
  -msan
        build code compatible with C/C++ memory sanitizer
  -mutexprofile file
        write mutex profile to file
  -nolocalimports
        reject local (relative) imports
  -o file
        write output to file
  -oldcomparable
        enable old comparable semantics
  -p path
        set expected package import path
  -pack
        write to file.a instead of file.o
  -pgoprofile file
        read profile from file
  -r    debug generated wrappers
  -race
        enable race detector
  -shared
        generate code that can be linked into a shared library
  -smallframes
        reduce the size limit for stack allocated objects
  -spectre list
        enable spectre mitigations in list (all, index, ret)
  -std
        compiling standard library
  -symabis file
        read symbol ABIs from file
  -t    enable tracing for debugging the compiler
  -traceprofile file
        write an execution trace to file
  -trimpath prefix
        remove prefix from recorded source file paths
  -v    increase debug verbosity
  -w    debug type checking
  -wb
        enable write barrier (default true)
```

Comment: I was hopeful, but unfortunately doesn't help, this just prints `no Go files in {current directory}` (using go 1.18.10).

Comment: hi @EdRandall sorry about that, I updated the guide